# The data I pass to another view is not working

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, data-binding

I'm new to swiftUI here and I want to try out to pass data between two views. But it doesn't seem to work.

I'm using Xcode 13.2 & iOS 15 for the simulator.

This is my code for the first view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var myName: String = ""

    var body: some View {
            
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                    
                TextField("Enter your name", text: $myName)
                
                Text(self.myName)
                
                NavigationLink(destination: BView(myName: self.$myName), label: {
                    Image(systemName: "arrowshape.turn.up.left")
                })
                
            }//: VSTACK
            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
        }//:NAVIGATION VIEW
        
    }
        

    }
```

This is code for the second view:

```
struct BView: View {
    @Binding var myName: String
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("BView")
            Text(self.myName)
            
        }//:NAVIGATION VIEW
    }
}
```

I want myName to be input in the first page which is ContentView() and then pass down the input data to BView().

Unfortunately, once I run it on the simulator, the input data doesn't;t show up.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine just add `VStack` in `BView`.

```
struct BView: View {
    @Binding var myName: String
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack { // HERE
                Text("BView")
                Text(self.myName)
            }
            
        }//:NAVIGATION VIEW
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use @EnvironmentObject to pass the data to view.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentobject